# Does the $K^1$-group of a complete flag variety vanish?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, flag-varieties

For $U(n)$ the Lie group of $n \times n$ unitary matrices, and $T^n$ its maximal torus subgroup, the homogeneous space
$$
U(n)/T^n
$$
is called the **complete flag variety** of order $n$. For the special case of $n=2$ this gives the sphere $S^2$. In this special case the topological $K$-theory group $K^1$ vanishes, i.e.
$$
K^1(S^2) = 0.
$$
Is this true for higher complete flag varieties? In explicit form, is it true that
$$
K^1(U(n)/T^n) = 0, ~~ \forall n?
$$

Comment: Yes. For any connected compact group, the quotient by the maximum torus has a CW-complex structure where all of the cells have even dimension, called Schubert cells (see also Bruhat). Compute $K$-theory by induction adding the cells one by one: it is a free abelian group on the cells, all in degree zero. Similarly, the cohomology is a free abelian group in dimensions of the cells. Why are the cells even dimensional? For $U(n)$ do by hand. One reason is that $K/T=G/B$ is an algebraic variety. But you should be able to see it directly from the compact. Maybe use T action eigenspaces are complex?